# Unexpected CDate() behavior

Tags: excel, vba, date, type-conversion

While going through some old code without error handling I stumbled upon unexpected [CDate() function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/concepts/getting-started/type-conversion-functions) behavior.

```
Sub Test()
    Dim userinput as Variant
    userinput = Application.Inputbox("Enter a date")
    'userinput will be a Variant/String with the inputs below
    Debug.Print CDate(userinput)
End Sub

Input: "27/8", "27/08", "27-8", "27-08", "27.8", "27.08"
Output: 27.08.2019 ' for all of the above

Input: "27.8.", "27.08."
Output: 04.10.1900, 31.05.1907
```

I was either expecting `Error 13: Type-mismatch`, or `27.08.1900` or `27.08.2019` as output.
What is happening with the latter two inputs? I can't wrap my head around it.

```
Additional input: "26.8." -> output: 24.09.1900
Input: "26.08." -> output: 20.02.1907
```

Regional setting is German (Germany) (Deutsch (Deutschland))
Date format is `DD.MM.YYYY`

**Edit:**
The complete userinput code looks like this:

```
Sub Test()
    Dim userinput As Variant
    Dim cancelBool As Boolean
    Do While Not ((IsDate(userinput) And Not userinput = vbNullString) Or cancelBool)
        userinput = Application.InputBox("Enter a date")
        If userinput = False Then cancelBool = True
        'the following line was inspired by Plutian
        If Not IsDate(userinput) And IsNumeric(userinput) Then userinput = userinput & Year(Now())
    Loop
    If Not cancelBool Then Debug.Print CDate(userinput)
End Sub
```

Comment: if you convert `24.08.1900` into an integer you get `268` I will assume cause not a full date is being entered, nor in the format xx/xx/xxxx your code is taking it as an integer and converting it into a date.

Comment: and `20.02.1907` is `2608`.. I should add 1 = 1st Jan 1900, 2 = 2nd Jan 1900 etc.. Decimal is the part of day.. thus 1.5 is midday 1st Jan 1900

Comment: Nice catch! Now the question remains why a `.` at the end makes it an integer...

Comment: and why is `26.8.` = `268` to many questions, not enough answers... do you have a decimal as a seperator for numbers?

Comment: do you have a decimal as a seperator for numbers? not dates.. asking as your code is most probably interpreting the "incomplete date" as a number with a decimal as an seperator.. id update your code so  a user has input a date in the required format others it rejects the input. no errors them

Comment: Misread your question, sorry. Period is a thousand's separater, a comma is for decimals.

Comment: A quick fix to get the expected behaviour would be to replace the troublesome ```.``` with a ```/``` by inserting ```userinput = Replace(userinput, ".", "/")``` in your code before print.

Comment: Well, no `CDate("27/08/")` will throw error 13. And in Germany short dates without a year are written as `DD.MM.` notice the period at the end. Though handling the problem is out of scope for this question.

Comment: True, but the error 13 is the expected cdate behaviour in this case, negating the ```.``` returning the input string as an integer. How the cdate output is formatted after is irrelevant. In this case your issue is not with the cdate function, but with handling incomplete input (with the year missing). It is indeed out of the scope of this question, but I'll take a look into it anyway and get back to you in a bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This doesn't appear to be a CDate behaviour problem, just a text-to-number conversion in general problem.

I have no citation, but from observation: When attempting to convert text to a numeric value, Excel will check to see if the text is an obvious date. If it's not, it will then strip out any *thousand's separator* - also local currency symbols, and other things, no doubt - to reduce the text to a number where possible.

So, on my English locale set up:

`"27.8"` *(`"27,8"` on yours)* is a recognisable decimal value
= 27 days and 8/10ths past `31/12/1899` = `26/01/1900 19:12:00`

`"27,8"` *(`"27.8"` on yours)* is a not recognisable decimal value, nor is it a recognisable date
so it becomes `"278"` as it strips out the 000 separators (commas on my set up, periods on yours)
278 days past `31/12/1899` = `27/09/1900`

As pointed out by @Nacorid however, `CDATE` treats this a little differently (to standard conversion) and attempts to resolve this to a date - being 27 Aug (current year).

`"27.8."` *(`"27,8,"` on yours)* throws an error, as is a not a recognisable date and due to the two decimal pointers an `Error` is produced.

`"27,8,"` *(`"27.8."` on yours)* is not a recognisable date, and Excel assumes the 000 separators need removing so converts this to 278
=278 days past `31/12/1899` = `04/10/1900`

So, the TL;DR is that **`"27.8."`** - while acceptable in German as a date - is not acceptable to Excel and you'll need to trap these and add an assumed year or similar to get around it.

Alternatively, consider adding a calendar pop-up form that forces the user to provide day, month and year.

Comment: `"27.8"` is correctly converted to `27/08/2019` though

Comment: You're right - I was analysing what Excel did when converting text to a number, not juts using `CDATE`. I've edited the answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Your issue here is not with the cdate function as it is giving the expected behaviour when the input is formatted as a string caused by the German custom of writing a date without the year as `dd.mm.`.
The issue is how to handle this input and still get the expected result, this can be achieved with the following code:

```vb
    If IsNumeric(userinput) Then
    Else
    userinput = CDate(userinput & Year(Now()))
    End If
```

Which forcefully inserts the current year in the user input when the variant is not recognised as numeric, which is caused by ending on a `.`. This works since dates in excel are always stored as a numeric value. Adding the year to the output converts it back to a numeric value which cdate can handle, since excel will now recognize the preferred separator as indeed a separator and handles it as a date as expected.

To me this would be a preferred alternative to forcing the user to amend their input. However wouldn't work if the required date is not in the current year, and might cause issues around new years. Alternatively you could replace the year snippet with a plain "0" or any year of your choice.

Comment: Oh, I like this one, I'll update my post with the complete part of the userinput

Comment: You're welcome. Sometimes the best way to handle a problem is not to solve it, but to find the quickest way around it.